# Endianness and OpenCL Transfers

Tags: opencl, endianness

In OpenCL, transfer from CPU client side to GPU server side is accomplished through `clEnqueueReadBuffer(...)`/`clEnqueueWriteBuffer(...)`.  However, the documentation does not specify whether any endian-related conversions take place in the underlying driver.

I'm developing on x86-64, and a NVIDIA card--both little endian, so the potential problem doesn't arise for me.

Does conversion happen, or do I need to do it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transfer do not do any conversions. The runtime does not know the type of your data.

You can probably expect conversions only on kernel arguments.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?  Also, I think the runtime _can_ figure out the type of the data.  You're passing an array of some type, so the driver could theoretically swap bytes around as needed during the transfer.

Comment: Baloney. How could the runtime know my buffer has floats vs. ints vs. RGBA pixel data? You infer far too much intelligence where none is needed nor exists.

Comment: Forgive me for perhaps being presumptuous, but does not `__kernel void op(__global float4* data1, int data2) {...}` mean that it takes _a float4 array_ and _a single int_ as arguments?

Comment: @Ian: You could create a buffer and upload data to it before compiling the kernel, so the swizzle couldn't happen during the upload. I suppose the swizzle could happen as the kernel reads or writes data, but I would expect the specification to say something about that.

Comment: I realized exactly that shortly after my last comment, but while away from a computer.  I agree that no conversions is probably what's happening.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16531000/fast-way-to-swap-endianness-using-opencl?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can query the device endianness (using `clGetDeviceInfo` and check  `CL_DEVICE_ENDIAN_LITTLE` ), but I am not aware of a way that allows transparent conversions.

Comment: Yes, I use this already.  That allows one to check the endianness of the device, but as far as I know it says nothing about _transferring_ data.

Answer (score 0):

This is the point, where INMHO the specification is not satisfactory.
At first it is clear about pointers, that is, data that a pointer is referencing can be in host or device byte order, and one can declare this by a pointer attribute, and the default byte order is that of the device.
So according to this, developers have to take care of the endianness that they feed as input to a kernel.
But than in "Appendix B - Portability" it's said that implementations may or may not automatically convert endianness of kernel arguments and that developers should consult the documentation of the vendors in case host and device byte order is different.
Sorry for me being that direct but what shit is that. I mean the intention of the OpenXX specifications is that they should make it possible to write cross platform code. But when there are that significant asspects that can vary from implementation to implementation, this is quite not possible.
The next point is, what does this all mean for OpenCL/OpenGL interoperation.
In OpenGL data for buffer objects like VBO's have to be in host byte order. So what in case such a buffer is shared between OpenCL and OpenGL. Must the data of it be transformed before and after they are processed by an OpenCL kernel or not?